# Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Tags: async-await, ethereum, web3js, metamask

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

App = {
    load: async () => {
        await App.loadWeb3(
        await App.loadAccount()
        )
    },



loadWeb3: async () => {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
    } else {
      window.alert("Please connect to Metamask.")
    }
    // Modern dapp browsers...
    if (window.ethereum) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum)
      try {
        // Request account access if needed
        await ethereum.enable()
        // Acccounts now exposed
        web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */})
      } catch (error) {
        // User denied account access...
      }
    }
    // Legacy dapp browsers...
    else if (window.web3) {
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider
      window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
      // Acccounts always exposed
      web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */})
    }
    // Non-dapp browsers...
    else {
      console.log('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!')
    }
  },

    loadAccount: async () => {
        App.account = web3.eth.accounts[0]
        console.log(App.account)
    }
}

$(() => {
    $(window).load(() => {
        App.load()
    })
})
```

The error is in LINE 1 where I get the accounts from Ganache but `await` is valid only for `async`.
What changes should I make in this code to remove the error? Please help me.

If I remove this line the error says that it cannot access accounts and after this `await` does not work.

Is there any way to make this piece of code in the form of an ASYNC function?

Answer (score 1):

`await` calls can only be made in functions marked as `async`. As you have used `await` in line 1 it is not wrapped in an `async` function. You can wrap your code in a `async` function and then call that function. e.g something like:

```js
const main = async () => { // <- the async wrapper function
 const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

 // .... rest of your code

 $(() => {
    $(window).load(() => {
        App.load()
    })
 })
}
main()
```

Or if you want to be more advanced and not save the function at all

```js
(async ()=>{
 const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
 // .... rest of your code
})() // <- call the function right after declaring it
```